# How to search in a multi dimensional array using VueJS or just javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js, frontend

I'm working on a Vue project and I'm just new to Vue JS, my question is how can I return all data that has an id of **1** when I input a value. below is a sample structure of my data.

```
 {
    'A': [{
        1: [{
            id: 1, 
            name: 'John'
        }],
        2: [{
            id: 5,
            name: 'Ken'
        }]
    }],
    'B': [{
        1: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Leena'
        }
    }],
    'C': [{
        1: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Jesica'
        }],
        2: [{
            id: 18,
            name: 'Mike'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Expected result should be (below), since they all have same id value

```
{
    'A': [{
        1: [{
            id: 1, 
            name: 'John'
        }]
    }],
    'B': [{
        1: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Leena'
        }
    }],
    'C': [{
        1: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Jesica'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: This is a weird data structure. Will each object property always contain an array containing only a single object?

Comment: no it's just an example, it could return multiple arrays as long as the input value is equal to field value that I want to search

Comment: So, say your object is named 'foo'. You mean `foo['A'][0][1]` could be an array of many objects, and you want any of those objects with `id==1` returned in the filtered array?

Comment: exactly @thanksd, here is what I'm trying to do on my app http://jsbin.com/dezokiwowu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Do you just need to filter an array of objects by an object property name? That's what it seems like in your app, which doesn't use this crazy data structure.

Comment: we do have different data structure, but the functionality from the example http://jsbin.com/dezokiwowu/edit?html,js,console,output is just what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any control over the format of the data structure, I would change it to something more manageable. For example, setting each capital letter property to an array of objects:

```
let dataset = { 
  'A': [{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id: 2, name: 'Sally'}],
  'B': [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}],
  ...
}
```

Even better would be to make the data structure an array of objects with a capital letter as a `group` property value and the id-name objects as `people` property values (or whatever would make sense to you):

```
let dataset = [{
    group: 'A', people: [{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id: 2, name: 'Sally'}],
  }, {
    group: 'B', people: [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}],
  }, {
    ...
}]
```

Using this structure, it would be relatively simple to filter the data by a specific id:

```
function filterObject(foo, id) {
  return foo.map(i => i.people.filter(j => j.id == id));
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/e2df3r5z/)

---

If you really need to use the crazy data structure you've provided, here's a function that will do what you need:

```
let filterObject = function(foo, id) {
  let bar = {};

  Object.keys(foo).map((key) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < foo[key].length; i++) {
      Object.keys(foo[key][i]).map((index) => {
        for (let j = 0; j < foo[key][i][index].length; j++) {
          if (foo[key][i][index][j].id != id) {
            continue;
          }

          if (!bar[key]) {
            bar[key] = [];
          }
          if (!bar[key][i]) {
            bar[key][i] = {};
          }
          if (!bar[key][i][index]) {
            bar[key][i][index] = [];
          }

          bar[key][i][index][j] = foo[key][i][index][j];
        }
      })
    }
  });

  return bar
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/zfd718jx/)

Comment: @PenAndPapers see my updated answer for a way to change your data structure to make the filtering function much simpler